# Calculating Measurement Conversions

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm brand new with C# and am taking a class where I'm struggling.

The assignment is to create a conversion application using a textbox value (valuetextbox) and have 2 listboxes holding measurements of inches, feet and yards.  The goal is to convert the the value based on the unit of measurement selected in the first listbox (selectedinitialunit) and post a value in a label based on the unit of measurement selected in the second listbox (selectedconvertedunit).  I'm missing how to do the comparison (math) between my selectedinitialunit and my selectedconvertedunit, based on the value entered into the valuetextbox.

```
namespace Measurement_Conversion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void convertedValueLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valueTextBox.Text = "";
        convertedValueLabel.Text = "";
        DesiredUnitBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        InitialUnitBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        valueTextBox.Focus();
    }

    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Declare Variables
        decimal initialvalue;
        decimal convertedvalue;
        string selectedInitialUnit;
        string selectedConvertedUnit;



        //Grab Initial Value
        initialvalue = int.Parse(valueTextBox.Text);

        //Determining Initial Unit has been selected.
        if (InitialUnitBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            selectedInitialUnit = InitialUnitBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Please select an Initial Unit of measurement."); }


        //Determining Desired Conversion Unit has been selected
        if (DesiredUnitBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            selectedConvertedUnit = DesiredUnitBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Please select a desired conversion unit of measurement."); }

        //Switch Statement
        switch (selectedInitialUnit)
        {
            case "Inches":
                convertedValueLabel.Text = ()
                break;
            case "Feet":
                break;
            case "Yards":
                break;


        }
    }



}
```

}

What I've written on paper says this - and it's not code, just my thought process:

```
if selectedinitialunit = INCHES and selectedconvertedunit = INCHES
then messagebox.show("Please select a different selectedconvertedunit");

else selectedinitialunit = INCHES and selectedconvertedunit = FEET
then convertedvaluelabel.Text = initialvalue/12;

else selectedinitialunit = INCHES and selectedconvertedunit = YARDS
then convertedvaluelabel.Text = initialvalue/36;
```

And so on for the other selected initial units.

Your help is most appreciated and I hope I'm not all over the place here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write code like this -

```
        string selectedUnit = selectedinitialunit.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string convertedUnit = selectedconvertedunit.SelectedItem.ToString();
        double valueToConvert = double.Parse(initialvalue.Text);
        if (selectedUnit.Equals(convertedUnit))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a different selectedconvertedunit");
        }
        else
        {
            switch (selectedUnit)
            {
                case "INCHES":
                    switch (convertedUnit)
                    {
                        case "FEET":
                            convertedvaluelabel.Text = (valueToConvert / 12.0).ToString();
                            break;
                        case "YARDS":
                            convertedvaluelabel.Text = (valueToConvert / 36.0).ToString();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

You can always add some sort of exception and error handling and validations in your code.

Comment: This was my solution.  Thank you so much, Ankit.  Now I'm going to build the rest of the measurement conversions.

Comment: Thanks DJDJ23. Keep asking questions on stack overflow and do upvote and accept useful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
//Switch Statement
switch (selectedInitialUnit + "->" + selectedconvertedunit)
{
    case "Inches->Feet":
        convertedValueLabel.Text = ()
        break;
    case "Feet->Inches":
        break;
    case "Yards->Feet":
        break;
    case "Yards->Yards":
    case "Feet->Feet":
        Messagebox.Show("Please select a different selectedconvertedunit");
        break;
}
```

**One other way is use `SelectedIndex` directly.**

Just post here for you know, I don't recommend use below code.

Example if `InitialUnitBox` and `DesiredUnitBox` have number items < 10 you can use:

```
switch (InitialUnitBox.SelectedIndex * 10 + DesiredUnitBox.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:       // = 0 * 10 + 0: first item of both box
    case 11:      // Same index both box
    case 22:      // Same index both box
        Messagebox.Show("Please select a different selectedconvertedunit");
        break;
    case 10:      // = 1 * 10 + 0: second item of InitialUnitBox and first item of DesiredUnitBox
        break;
    case 11:      // = 1 * 10 + 1
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to choose one "base" measurement and convert to that measurement and then again from that measurement.

It can even be meters or millimeters. This way you only need 2 (if you choose inches, for example) or 3 multipliers to get it straight.

```
const double InchesInFoot = 12;
const double InchesInYard = InchesInFoot * 3;

// step 1
double valueInches = input * constant above according to input measurement;

// step 2
double result = valueInches / constant according to output measurement;
```

you can also use matrix like

```
        double[,] factors = new double[3, 3] {
            { 1.0, 1.0/12, 1.0/12/3 },
            { 12.0, 1, 1.0/3 },
            { 12*3,3,1 }
        };

        const int Inches = 0;
        const int Feet = 1;
        const int Yards = 2;

        var result = factors[Yards, Inches] * 1;
```

this will make it even easier to read, but you need to do more math upfront.

I guess that would require you to understand multi-dimensional arrays and things, as well like a little more math than required.